# How to run jar file with -D and -classpath options in Linux

Tags: java

I trying to run a jar file with the -D option and multiple jar files in the classpath. How can I do that in linux?

Here is my command.

```
java -cp -Dcom.sun.management.config.file=/usr/local/monitor/jmx-management.properties .:/usr/local/monitor/monitor.jar:/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/ojdbc6.jar com.mypackage.Monitor
```

When I run this I'm getting an error " Could not find or load main class .:.usr.local.monitor.monitor.jar:.usr.lib.oracle.11.2.client64.lib.ojdbc6.jar"

Comment: move the `-cp` before the `.:/usr/local...`...

Comment: You are not providing a value to the -cp switch. It expects the classpath, probably something like -cp . for example. Or wherever your JARs and CP is.

Comment: I moved the -cp before the .:/usr/local... Now it says cannot find or load main class com.mypackage.Monitor